# Spark Java aggregate timestamp by intervals e.g. aggregate every 10 minutes

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by

I have a data with timestamps and would like to aggregate them into 10-minute intervals. I tried to groupBy, however, timestamps can only be split into hourly intervals without using any UDF.

Sample data

```
id  timestamp
b   2/22/2022 8:31
a   2/22/2022 8:37
b   2/22/2022 8:46
b   2/22/2022 9:46
a   2/22/2022 9:48
```

Result wanted

```
interval    timestamp   id
   1    2/22/2022 8:31  b
   1    2/22/2022 8:37  a
   2    2/22/2022 8:46  b
   3    2/22/2022 9:46  b
   3    2/22/2022 9:48  a
```